# Multi-site for user groups

Tags: multi-sites

I have to carry out a procedure for the management of information by a group of users. Later I could have the same need but for a group of different users. Since I haven't understood how the multisite works, I can't make up my mind.

The software will be the same, but for database copy, user management and security issues, I would prefer to have the database different for the group of users.

1. Can the multisite manage multiple databases with a single software?
2. Do I have to foresee it and create it from the beginning or can I create the software and subsequently, if there is a request, transforming it into a multisite?

Comment: Multisites are totally different sites with the same codebase but different databases. If you have N sites in a multisite Drupal setup is the same as having N different sites that share the same codebase. So, use multisite if you want to have the same codebase for the sites and consider a good feature the fact that you can update the codebase for all the sites updating just one codebase directory (what at the same time means you CAN'T make sites use a different codebase, you update one you update all, you can't do incremental updates).

Comment: Did you already read through https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multisite and started to test it locally for example?

Comment: Not at the moment. I finish developing the windows software with data acquisition via excel sheets, then the user checks phase. If all goes well, I start the development phase with Drupal. But I thought it important to understand how to get started. I thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can the multisite manage multiple databases with a single software?

Yes.

> 2. Do I have to foresee it and create it from the beginning or can I create the software and subsequently, if there is a request, transforming it into a multisite?

You can perfectly start with a single site, and late on transform it into a multisite.

As an alternative to using a multisite, you may also want to consider using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module. From the specs in your question, it appears to me that only using this module (without a multisite setup), it could well be sufficient ...